# How could I make a request like this in Retrofit2

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a task. 
I wanna make a request to the server with this pattern and using Retrofit2:

http://server.com?test[{My data: String}]={My SecondData: Int}.

Example: http://server.com?test[ifD3234oeW]=10

Can you show me a function in interface which will solve my problem?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create a function in API interface:**

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@GET
retrofit2.Call<"return_type"> testServer(@Url String url); }
```

**2. create an instance of interface where you want to use:**

```
public ApiInterface apiInterface;
```

**3. make API call**

```
apiInterface = ApiClient.GetApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

            retrofit2.Call<"return_type"> result = apiInterface.testServer(url);

            result.enqueue(new Callback<return_type>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<return_type> call, Response<return_type> response) {
                    if (response != null){
                           //do something
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<return_type> call, Throwable t) {
                   //do something
                }
            });
```

Comment: so it means I can't do it with retrofit annotations? Such as Query, Path etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below

```
public interface ServiceInterface {

    @GET("?test[{first_data}]={second_data}")
    Call<POJO> getData(
        @Path("first_data") String firstData,
        @Path("second_data") int secondData
    );

}
```

Replace POJO (return type for Call) and also replace variable names according to your requirement.

**Note**: I haven't tested the above code.